# I have to display modal when button is clicked. It worked but I can't close the modal because close buttons are disabled

Tags: button, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, simplemodal, showmodaldialog

when modal opens whole page turning to disabled so I can't click anywhere on the page

I am using bootstrap's modal plugin. there are another libraries also. I don't think this is the problem. Otherwise modal wouldn't open